# Moving to Florida to live with my fiancé

Tags: usa, portuguese-citizens

I'm a Portuguese citizen and I'm moving to USA, Florida to live and get married to my US fiancé. What do I need to get into the country? As far as I understood I can request for a Fiancé visa. Am I suppose to buy a return ticket or just a one-way ticket?
Thanks so much and I hope you are able to help me out.

Comment: Do not buy any tickets before you get your visa.  Your fiancee must petition for you; the process takes months.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. This is a real marriage, not a scheme to get a green card. Our intentions are for me to move at the end of March as we want to organize our wedding and of course to start our life together.

Comment: I don't have direct experience with this but a little searching on the internet suggests that it will take four to eight months, with five or six months being the common duration.

Comment: The fiancé visa is not always the best option.  A tourist visa might be more practical.  I suggest your fiancé call or visit the US consulate in Portugal or wherever he is currently located, to ask which one would be more practical, and to also discuss the ramifications of marrying inside the US after arrival vs. outside the US before traveling. // Eventually you will want to document your shared history together for your green card application.  I'm not sure, possibly it would be helpful to start putting together a photo album?  Plus, a photo album would be fun to have later.